# Converting enum to int

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I have the following enum

```
public enum TESTENUM
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

I then want to use this to compare to an integer variable that I have, like this:

```
if ( myValue == TESTENUM.Value1 )
{
}
```

But in order to do this test I have to cast the enum as follows (or presumably declare the integer as type enum):

```
if ( myValue == (int) TESTENUM.Value1 )
{
}
```

Is there a way that I can tell the compiler that the enum is a series of integers, so that I don’t have to do this cast or redefine the variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You need to cast the enum value. If you don't want to cast, then consider using a class with constant int values:

```
class static EnumLikeClass
{
    public const int Value1 = 1;
    public const int Value2 = 2;
}
```

However, there are some downsides to this; the lack of type safety being a big reason to use the `enum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the enum that it contains integers:

```
public enum TESTENUM: int
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
}
```

However you have to still cast them manually,

Comment: All enums are int by default.

Comment: you dont have to provide :Int as it is by default.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that casting the enum value in your context is exactly **how** you tell the compiler that "look here, I know this enum value to be of type int, so use it as such".

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't (unlike C++), and for a good reason of type safety.