# Safe (in the C# sense) way to implement something with pointers

Tags: c#, pointers

```
            ...
            {
                int *r1, *r2;
                r1 = GetCorrectRegister(first);
                r2 = GetCorrectRegister(second);
                switch ((OpCode)current.opcode)
                {
                    case OpCode.ADDR:
                        r2 = r1 + r2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            ...
```

This is the obvious, easiest way to solve this problem. However, I'd prefer not to use an unsafe method if I can avoid it. Basically, I have a bunch of integers which represent registers. There are assembly instructions that take register mnemonics as arguments. I'd prefer not to have the logic to determine which variable to assign to in each branch of the switch statement or make some sort of kludgey GetRegisterValue(mnemonic) and SetRegisterValue(mnemonic) functions. Is there some C#y way to do something similar?

Comment: use Delegates in C# it can act as functional pointers

Comment: r2=r1+r2 ? You meant *r2=*r1+*r2, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I meant *r2=*r1+*r2, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a bunch of integers which
>   represent registers

The obvious thing here is not to have a bunch of integers. Create an array

```
 int[] registers = new int[NUMBER_OF_REGISTERS];
```

Your above code turns into

```
    {
            int r1Index, r2Index;
            r1Index = GetCorrectRegisterIndex(first);
            r2Index = GetCorrectRegisterIndex(second);
            switch ((OpCode)current.opcode)
            {
                case OpCode.ADDR:
                    registers[r1Index] = registers[r1Index] + registers[r2Index];
                    break;
            }


     }
```

Additionally, use an `enum` to create symbolic names for your register names where each name gives you the right index.

Comment: If I wanted to index into an array using an enum value, I'd have to cast every time, right? registers[(int)Registers.A]?

Comment: @Paul: yes, that is true, read this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091267/converting-enum-to-int for more information.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a class and ref parameters?

```
class Registers
{
    public int EAX;
    public int EBX;
    //...

    public void ExecuteBinaryOperation(int opCode, ref int r1, ref int r2)
    {
        // ...
        // binary operation ADD.
        r2 = r1 + r2;
        //...
    }
}
```

and in code:

```
registers.ExecuteBinaryOperation(0, ref registers.EAX, ref registers.EBX);
```